# Laplace Transformations to solve Differential Equation with one initial condition.

Tags: laplace-transform

Solve y'+4y+5$\int_0^x y dx $ = e^{-x}
y(0) = 0

I have tried deriving both sides first, but then come to the issue that we don't know what y'(0) equals so we can't solve for L[y].  Similarly, I tried taking the Laplace Transform of both sides but will run into the problem of having y in the final equation of the form L[y] = ...*y.

Comment: What is the Laplace transform of the LHS that you are getting?

Comment: L[y']+4L[y]+5yL[x] = L[e^{-x}]

Comment: $L[\int_0^x y(x) dx] = \frac{L[y(x)]}{s}$

Comment: So when working with first order ODE's, y is always a function of x? i.e. y= y(x)? I haven't worked with ODE's in a while so I think I forgot the basics.  But my textbook does have this Laplace equation right before the question I asked so it makes sense to use it. Thank you!

Comment: One way to view it is the opposite direction: if $z=\int_0^x y dx$ then $z$ satisfies a second order IVP with two given initial conditions, since $y=z'$.

Comment: Yes, basically an ODE says there's some unknown function $y$ of an independent variable $x$, and all we know is some relationship between $y$ and its derivatives, e.g. $y^\prime (x) = F(y(x),x)$ is a first order ODE and $y^{\prime\prime} (x) = F(y^\prime (x),y(x),x)$ is a second order ODE.

Comment: I see, thank you AlexanderJ93! It seems my use of shorthand notation has made me forget a bit of the basics. To Ian, I will consider that as well! Thanks to you both.